# cld() output has a wrong order of factor levels

Tags: r

I am using R cld() function with emmeans, but the order of factor level in the output is different from what I set. Before calling cld(), the by.years output is also in the desired order ([screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3wUEN.png)), but when I do cld(), the output is in the alphabetical order of Light - Moderate - No([screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/rmPRs.png)). I also checked cld.years$Grazing.intensity, the levels are correct. Is there a way to specify the order of factor levels in the cld() output? Any help is appreciated.

```
# sample data
plants <- structure(list(Grazing.intensity = structure(c(3L, 2L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 1L, 3L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 3L, 3L), .Label = c("Light-grazing", "Moderate-grazing", "No-grazing"), class = "factor"), Grazing.intensity1 = structure(c(3L, 2L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 1L, 3L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 3L, 3L), .Label = c("LG", "MG", "NG"), class = "factor"), Years = structure(c(1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 2L), .Label = c("Dry-year", "Wet-year"), class = "factor"), Month = structure(c(2L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 3L, 3L, 1L, 1L, 3L, 1L, 3L, 3L, 2L, 2L, 3L), .Label = c("Aug.", "Jul.", "Sept."), class = "factor"), Plots = c(1L, 3L, 8L, 6L, 9L, 7L, 2L, 2L, 10L, 10L, 7L, 7L, 9L, 4L, 2L), Species.richness = c(8L, 6L, 10L, 11L, 9L, 5L, 7L, 13L, 10L, 6L, 5L, 5L, 14L, 8L, 10L)), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, -15L))

# set the order of factor levels
plants$Grazing.intensity <- factor(plants$Grazing.intensity, levels = 
                                     c('No-grazing','Light-grazing','Moderate-grazing'))

attach(plants)
lmer.mod <- lmer(Species.richness ~ Grazing.intensity*Years + (1|Month), data = plants)

by.years <- emmeans(lmer.mod, specs = ~ Grazing.intensity:Years, by = 'Years', type = "response")

# display cld
cld.years <- cld(by.years, Letters = letters)
```

This is my first time posting sample data in StackOverflow, so it may be wrong.. I used dput().

Comment: You’re writing R code, not RStudio code, so there’s no need to refer to it in the title or body of the question.

Answer (score 0):

I solved the issue. The order changed because the levels are displayed in the increasing order of emmean. I set `sort = FALSE`, and the result was displayed in the default order. I should have read the [documentations](https://www.rdocumentation.org/packages/lsmeans/versions/2.27-62/topics/cld) more thoroughly.